# Can't migrate django databases on MySQL after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu

Reinstalled system on ubuntu 16.04 and when first trying to run `python manage.py makemigrations` got the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1193, "Unknown system variable 'storage_engine'")
```

My django databases settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'license_portal',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            "init_command": "SET storage_engine=MyISAM",
        },
    },
}
```

Libraries:

```
(mmslic) ➜  mmsLicenseServer git:(master) ✗ pip freeze              
Django==1.8.12
django-admin-bootstrapped==2.5.7
django-bootstrap3==7.0.1
MySQL-python==1.2.5
mysqlclient==1.3.7
requests==2.9.1
(mmslic) ➜  mmsLicenseServer git:(master) ✗ dpkg -l | grep -i mysql            
ii  libmysqlclient-dev                            5.7.12-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        MySQL database development files
ii  libmysqlclient20:amd64                        5.7.12-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  libmysqlclient20:i386                         5.7.12-0ubuntu1                                     i386         MySQL database client library
ii  libqt4-sql-mysql:i386                         4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2                               i386         Qt 4 MySQL database driver
ii  mysql-client-5.7                              5.7.12-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-client-core-5.7                         5.7.12-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        MySQL database core client binaries
ii  mysql-common                                  5.7.12-0ubuntu1                                     all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ii  mysql-server                                  5.7.12-0ubuntu1                                     all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-server-5.7                              5.7.12-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-5.7                         5.7.12-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: do you really, really want to use myisam?

Comment: @middlestump I couldn't get INNODB to work and it's quite a low performance service, so the DB throughput would not be an issue!

Comment: But innodb is default in recent versions of mysql so it works out of the box

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After struggling with this issue I've found that the problem was a change on MySQL 5.7 version.

With MySQL 5.7 the command `SET storage_engine=MyISAM` won't work, so that was the problem!

As spotted on the [MySQL 5.7 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html) use `default_storage_engine` instead!  My configuration became:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'license_portal',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            "init_command": "SET default_storage_engine=MyISAM",
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It should be pointed out, that this Error can arise when using http://seafile.com and updating the underlying MySQL-Server. See also this issue on gitlab (https://github.com/haiwen/seafile/issues/1776) .

Comment: I had recently made a clean install of Mac OS and while installing mysql-server with brew forgot to specify the version - and the default 5.7 got installed. Thank you!